# How to Calculate How Many Times Inputs Entered in Sentinel Loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, sentinel

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVCxG.jpg) is the link to the programming question for detail. I have done my source code but I don't know how to calculate and display how many times inputs are entered in sentinel loop. Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i, hours;
  int tot_clients = 0;
  float charges;
  float tot_collection = 0;
  const int sentinel = -1;

  cout << "Welcome to ABC Parking Services Sdn Bhd" << endl;
  cout << "=======================================" << endl;

  while (hours != sentinel) {
    cout << "Please enter number of parking hours (-1 to stop)" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    if (hours <= 2 && hours > 0) {
      charges = 1.00 * hours;
      cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;
    }
    else if (hours > 2 && hours <= 12) {
      charges = (1.00 * 2) + ((hours - 2) * 0.50);
      cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;
    }
    else if (hours > 12) {
      charges = 10.00 * hours;
      cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;
    }
    else if (hours == sentinel) {
      break;
    }

    tot_collection = tot_collection + charges;
  }

  cout << "SUMMARY OF REPORT" << endl;
  cout << "=======================================" << endl;

  cout << "Total clients:" << tot_clients << endl;
  cout << "Total colletion:" << tot_collection << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help me solving this. I am studying for my programming final exam.

Comment: To begin with you use the variable `hours` before it has been initialized, which means its value will be *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior*. Perhaps a do-while loop would be better here?

Comment: emmm but the question asked to write in sentinel loop. :')

Comment: And a `do ... while(...)` loop is still a loop. :)

Comment: have you click the image? there is my programming question. btw, could you please show me? i dont get it haha.

Comment: Don't post image when you can avoid it. You can copy the content of your homework into text. The image is too small. I don't understand why people answer you.

Comment: sorry if my question confusing and thanks fr the feedback of the image, this is my first time using this web.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you want to count the number of clients (tot_clients). You have already intitalised the tot_clients = 0. This is good. You just have to increment the tot_clients variable inside the while loop (tot_clients++).

```
while (hours != sentinel)
{
    cout << "Please enter number of parking hours (-1 to stop)" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    tot_clients++; //this is the code to be added

    /*rest of the code remains same*/
```

Comment: omg thaaaaaaanks hahah this helps me lots sorry if my question confusing huhu but glad you understand what i meant!

Answer (score 2):

Add `tot_clients++;` just before or after `tot_collection = tot_collection + charges;`

Answer (score 1):

1- initialize **hours=0** otherwise hour will have some undetermined value during first-time condition check of while loop.
2-i am assuming that **tot_clients** stores total no. of customers than,
you just need to increment tot_clients on each iteration

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int i, hours=0;
    int tot_clients=0;
    float charges;
    float tot_collection=0;
    const int sentinel = -1;

    cout << "Welcome to ABC Parking Services Sdn Bhd" << endl;
    cout << "=======================================" << endl;

    while (hours != sentinel)
    {
    cout << "Please enter number of parking hours (-1 to stop)" << endl;
    cin >> hours;`

    if (hours <= 2 && hours >0)
    {
        charges = 1.00 * hours;
        cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;
    }

    else if (hours>2 && hours <=12)
    {
        charges = (1.00*2) + ((hours - 2) * 0.50);
        cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;         
    }

    else if (hours > 12)
    {
        charges = 10.00 * hours;
        cout << "Charges: " << charges << endl;         
    }

    else if (hours == sentinel)
    {
        break;
    }

    tot_collection = tot_collection + charges;  
    tot_clients=tot_clients+1; //increment's on each iteration except on input -1

}


cout << "SUMMARY OF REPORT" << endl;
cout << "=======================================" << endl;

cout << "Total clients:" << tot_clients << endl;
cout << "Total colletion:" << tot_collection << endl;

return 0;

}
```

`

Comment: hoho thaaanks. =))